# Trying to install Canon LBP7750Cdn driver on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: drivers, canon, printing

I'n new to Ubuntu/Linux and had significant difficulties while attempting to configure my printer to work. The automatic driver pairing wizard which Ubuntu uses to identify and install the appropriate drivers did not find my printer's driver.
I managed to get it to print when I manually select the generic configuration and checked the PCL6 configuration. However, the printer driver wizard does provide a list of Canon printers and actually do specify my printer as LBP7750C (minus the "dn" at the end, I'm assuming its because duplex ability and networking is not present on all the models - I'm not sure if this could be the source of the problem), but in selecting this option and trying to print I receive this message:

> Idle - /usr/lib/cups/filter/foomatic-rip failed

I searched for this similar problem which other users might have encountered, but while there where plenty of such cases, they all had different resolutions and were all related to HP printers.
Canon actually do provide a driver for my printer, but it comes with no installation instructions unless you consider yourself an experienced *CUPS* guru. Seriously.

If anyone can help me solve this **foomatic-rip failed** problem I'd be really grateful - and I'm sure many other folks too. [BTW, can't Canonical fix this type of thing for the next Ubuntu release? - I't seems like a small problem but it causes many problems and countles hours of production time loss.]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think you relied on Ubuntu to supply the printer driver needed;

Canon provide drivers that you need to use;
[Canon LBP7750 Driver](http://www.canon.co.uk/Support/Consumer_Products/products/printers/Laser/i-SENSYS_LBP7750Cdn.aspx?type=download&page=1)

You are using Ubuntu: it uses .deb packages (also known as debian packages)

You need to work out if you are using 32bit or 64bit;

You might find you get better help on the Ubuntu forum: in the hardware section is usually where people ask for printer help;

Post number 4 (often written as #4) in this [thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1982917)

talks about how a Canon LBP printer is installed

Sivella (the person doing post #4) is french and maintains the french LBP support page for Ubuntu